# Is there another way to refer to the "proximal interphalangeal joints"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a character making a certain motion, sitting at a desk and resting his head on his hand, basically. But, instead of the face resting in an open palm, I'm imagining the hand mostly closed. Not tensely, but just closed. In this case, the face tends to meet the hand not at the **knuckles** of the fingers, which are technically the **metacarpophalangeal joints**, but instead at the **proximal interphalangeal joints**.

[image: Diagram of hand bones]

How do I describe this contact between the character's face and his hand specifically at that point, without using such a technical word?

One phrase that came to mind was *inner knuckles*, but I'm not sure if that only makes sense to me, or most would picture the correct set of knuckles from "inner."

Comment: You might get better answers at [biology.se].

Comment: Actually, what you're describing is what most people would call the knuckles.  The knuckles are what you knock on a door with.

Comment: @HotLicks - I was thinking of fights and brass knuckles, which definitely refer to the metacarpophalangeal joints. But you're totally right that when you mentioned "knocking doors" and "knuckles" in one sentence, I felt no conflict in words. But perhaps that's because with knocking doors, it's very clear what is meant by "knuckles"? Whereas in my case, it could be either set of knuckles (for example, putting the metacarpophlangeal to your chin or mouth, versus the PIP to your cheekbone).

Comment: May be a UK/US thing.

Comment: Looking at several online dictionaries, it appears that "knuckle" generally refers to *any* finger joint.

Comment: I tried it two ways, [The Thinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thinker#/media/File:The_Thinker,_Rodin.jpg) pose, and with the fingers curled (not into a fist, but with the PIP cocked). In either case, I wound up not resting my face on the *backs of my fingers*, not on any of the knuckles. Resting my face on any set of knuckles was uncomfortable.

Comment: @JEL, I meant to capture a moment when an absentminded person begins to rest their head but is lost in thought and doesn't quite. They are sort of hanging there, two PIP knuckles "docked" into the groove beneath a cheekbone, with almost no transfer of weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common term is "second knuckle, as in "I ran my second knuckles back and forth across my shirt."  They are the knuckles just below what people simply refer to as "knuckles."  My niece calls it the *knee* of her finger.

Answer (score 0):

**Finger joints** would probably be understood as being these particular joints, because you're not using the word knuckles, and because the other joint of each finger doesn't bend much without special training. This is of course not technically precise, but has this advantage of avoiding any technicality.

And it's much more common than "second knuckles":
[image: http://i.imgur.com/18YF7Di.png]

EDIT: Well, that's cheating, as that's also a carpentry term. Not sure you can get an N-gram ignoring pages related to carpentry?